# Does each PDE's have a strong link to a Particular Stochastic Process

Tags: partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, heat-equation, stochastic-differential-equations

Brownian Motion has a deep link to the heat PDE. Studying the dynamics of a particle  moving (as if undergoing Brownian Motion)  one can derive the heat equation. Also looking at the generator of the Markov Semi-group of Brownian Motion, we see it is the Laplacian (and by the differential property of the semi-group $d_{t}\mathcal{P}_{t}f=L\mathcal{P}_{t}f$ )  we again see a connection between the two.

Firstly - Applying this link to the real world has it got something to do with heat just being the movement of particles (my physics is terrible haha)?

Secondly - I was wondering if other PDE's each have similar links to some Stochastic Process?

Answer (score 4):

There is the [Fokker-Planck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation) equation of an Ito process. Basically every PDE of the form

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}=-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\mu p\right)+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\left(\frac{\sigma^2}{2} p\right)$$

is the evolution of the transition density of related Ito process satisfying the SDE:

$$dX_t=\mu(t,X_t) dt+\sigma(t,X_t) dW_t$$

Letting $\mu\equiv 0$ and $\sigma\equiv 1$ corresponds to Brownian motion and heat equation.

Also related is [Feynman Kac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula).

Also, related to your question about heat and particles - a resounding **yes**. Check Einstein's or Smoluchowski's arguments. Particles undergo a random walk, randomly bumping into other particles. Because the number of particles is so high we can apply the central limit theorem/Donsker's theorem to get that the macroscopic behavior is a Brownian motion.